# Applet console logs

Tags: java, applet, console

I have a web applet hosted on a server. 
I am using FireFox to load that applet and perform some actions. 
I see that Java console logs are getting lost after sometime (seems applet calls `system.gc` and it clears everything)

1. Assuming that I do not have control of applet, what can I do to save all the applet console logs into a log file?
2. In case above is not possible , assuming that I do have control on applet code what can I do to make sure that I save all Java console logs on applet?

When I say lost , I mean truncated  to contain last 1000 lines or so . I need all the logs that are coming .

Comment: `gc` will only clear objects from memory if nothing references them, so obviously the problem lies elsewhere.  Further, the 'applet logs' as they exist, will appear in the Java Console, which is an entirely client side facility.  To store those logs on the server would require. 1) For the applet to redirect output to the server. 2) For the server to provide a facility to receive the information, and write it to file.

Answer (score 0):

By default, applet console log redirect for "<User Application Data Folder>\Sun\Java\Deployment\log" (windows).

please see follow document.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/console_trace_log.html